# NOT IN example, order difference

Tags: mysql, sql

The Question:

The database has the following relations: 
Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)

Get all the ship's classes of Russia. If there are no classes of Russia in the database, get all the classes in the database.
Result set: country, class

---

Can anyone tell me whats the difference between these 2 statements, I dont get how they differ.(The first query is WRONG and the second query will WORK)

```
select distinct country, class from classes 
where country not in (select country from classes where country='Russia') 
or country='Russia'
```

VS

```
select distinct country, class 
from classes 
where 'Russia' 
not in (select country from classes) 
or country='Russia'
```

Comment: Your query won't make any sense cause you are contradicting the conditions.

Comment: `A=B or A!=B` never make sense actually.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query same as saying

```
select distinct country, 
class 
from classes 
where country != 'Russia' or country='Russia'
```

So, `where country != 'Russia'` will fetch all rows where country is not `russia`.

`or country='Russia'` will fetch row that contains country as `russia`

Which is again same as saying cause essentially you are fetching all rows

```
select distinct country, 
class 
from classes
```

Your second query

```
select distinct country, class 
from classes 
where Russia 
not in (select country from classes) 
or country='Russia'
```

When you say `where 'Russia' not in (select country from classes)` it will not fetch anything cause `Russia` is not a column. So essentially you are filtering out all rows but

`or country='Russia'` will fetch the row with country value as `russia`. That's why you get your so called desired result (which actually a incorrect way of doing it).

Second query is same as saying

```
select distinct country, class 
from classes 
where country='Russia'
```

In case you want to test it, try this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a606a/5

Comment: I agree with everything you said about the first query. However, in the second query what you said "When you say where 'Russia' not in (select country from classes) it will not fetch anything cause Russia is not a column....." is not true..it is not equilvent to "select distinct....country = 'Russia'. You can test it out in the link you sent me, remove Russia in your scheme and run your code compared to the second query i have, they will provide different results

Comment: @user3681831, as I have mentioned in my answer .. just run the part `select distinct country, class from classes where 'Russia' not in (select country from classes)` and see by yourself if it returns any rows. In your 2nd query you are getting 1 row with country as russia only because of the `OR country='Russia'`

Comment: ya but what you said was the second query is techinally: "select distinct country, class  from classes where country='Russia'" which isnt because the second query covers two cases, if russia is actually in the database and if russia is not in database. FOr example, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13af9/3  , now try running "select distinct country, class from classes where 'Russia' not in (select country from classes)" and it will find all the countries

Comment: @user3681831, correct. My posted explanation/example was based on the data or per post (assuming that russia is one of the valid value in country column). Now you are getting cause there is no country value called russia. Don't get confused.

Comment: ok, but the question was initially: "Get all the ship's classes of Russia. If there are NO classes of Russia in the database, get all the classes in the database. Result set: country, class." I was just trying to find the logic behind the second query, mostly "where 'Russia' not in (select country from classes)" and how it differs country not in (select....where = russia)